# Codeigniter + Wordpress site_url issue

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

Hello
For some reason echoing site_url gives me http://mydomain/**blog** instead of http://mydomain.
In config.php i have
`$config['base_url']= "http://mydomain/";` and
 `$config['index_page'] = "";`

I have a blog folder in my root directory that contains the wordpress.
Where **blog** segment comes from and how can i remove it?
I have a problem because it appears in every redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is defined in wp-app.php and is the base url + the folder of the WP installation.

I assume you are talking about wordpress redirects, and you would like to redirect to your main site instead of the wordpress installation?

You might want to use home_url() instead...

> The site_url template tag retrieves
>   the site url for the current site
>   (where the WordPress core files) with
>   the appropriate protocol, 'https' if
>   is_ssl() and 'http' otherwise. If
>   scheme is 'http' or 'https', is_ssl()
>   is overridden.
>
> The home_url template tag retrieves
>   the home url for the current site with
>   the appropriate protocol, 'https' if
>   is_ssl() and 'http' otherwise. If
>   scheme is 'http' or 'https', is_ssl()
>   is overridden.